# Firestore emulator displays 'ok'

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

When I launch firestore with that command:

```
firebase emulators:start
```

I get :

[image]
There is no mention of firestore GUI, though I have installed the latest firesebase-tools.

When I get to the mentionned url : http://localhost:4040/

It only returns "ok" and I do not have access to the user interface to manipulate data.
[image]

From Firebase tutorial video from 24th June 2020 I see that it is supposed to write "Gui: emulator GUI started at http://localhost:4000".

[image]

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: You can change the ports manually via the [firebase.json file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#configure_emulator_suite). Maybe some changes were done (not intentionally) which caused the port to change.

Comment: Still, that does not explain why you see the "ok"... let me check that

Comment: I think there something missing. On the second image, you showed the logs after the Firestore Emulator host that was started on port 4500 **and then** the GUI port was shown. However, on your first image it was never shown the Port for the GUI. Please share your logs until the GUI part and let us know if the provided address and port are working as expected.

Comment: My guess is: When accessing to localhots from port 4040 you are only checking the status of the Emulator itself and the "ok" is expected because it is telling us that it is working properly. But I think having the full log from your first image will help

Comment: The second image is extracted from the Google tutorial video ! @KevinQuinzel

Comment: There is only what is copied in the console !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was not related to firestore,

for some reasons firebase-tool was not updated properly , so I had to manually delete npm global folders and then reinstall firebase-tools.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I did the following steps to access the firebase GUI:

0. Install firebase tools: `npm install -g firebase-tools`
1. Firebase login: `firebase login --no-localhost`
2. Firebase setup: `firebase init`
3. Start emulator(s): `firebase emulators:start --only firestore` for starting only the firestore emulator or `firebase emulators:start` to start them all.

I've also found this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/learn/pathways/firebase-emulators) about emulators very helpful.